# top: failed tty get

Tags: top

I am running following script to monitor some processes and store the output in html file. But on running, it gives the error `top: failed tty get`.
Here is the script:

```
var=4
while [ $var -ge 0 ]
do
`echo q | htop --p=2164 | aha --black --line-fix >> htop2.html`
#$cmd
sleep 1
var=$(($var-1))
done
```

Please guide me to solve this error!

Comment: Are you running the script from a cron job? Is that the exact script that generated that error?

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me, that you don't have *htop* installed.
What's the output of `which htop` and `alias`? Most likely the command *htop* points to *top* on your system. Contrary to *htop*, *top* cannot be used in non-interactive environments/scripts.
Try to install the 'real' *htop*.

Comment: The error looks like it's from `top`, not `htop`, but wouldn't `top` have complained about the `--p` option?  Also notice the strange command substitution in the code. I don't think we're seeing the code that generated that exact error.